# Is the sentence "Où est-ce que as-tu acheté celui-là" correct?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative

In the sentence

> Où est-ce que as-tu acheté celui-là ?

Why is the "tu as" inverted?

Shouldn't it be

> Où as-tu acheté celui-là ?

Or

> Où est-ce que tu as acheté celui-là ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are totally right, both your alternatives would be correct while the first one is not.